# Can I save a TiledMap in libGDX?

Tags: serialization, libgdx, tmx, tiled

I just started to look into libGDX and I really enjoyed it. Loading a tile map I generated with an editor was really simple. But I have in mind to work on a game where the player can modify and extend the map.

So here is my question: Is it somehow possible to add/delete/change fields in a `com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap` and save the result to disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now there is no built-in feature to store `TiledMaps`.

I know only the .tmx format of TilEd, but this is a pretty easy and straight-forward XML format, which is very similar to the structure of a `TiledMap`. Check out how [`TmxMapLoader`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.html) loads the `TiledMap` and then use an [`XmlWriter`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlWriter.html) to write your altered maps to a file in a similar way.

Comment: I just saw that a lib called 'kryo' can be used for serialization. Maybe that is another possibility. Otherwise I'll have to write the writer...

Comment: Okay, in case you do not want to open your modified maps in the editor, binary serialization might of course be an option.